# I am trying to add a mode rewrite rule to wordpress that seems to fail

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I am trying to redirect everything from /app/.... to a certain page - will use that later for angular js.

This is what I came up with :

`add_rewrite_rule('/app/.*', 'index.php?page_id=11', 'top');`

However this doesn't work...

In `settings->permalink` when I set it to: `domain/sample-post/` - it sami-working `domain.com/app/{number}` will work and redirect to app - nothing else though. like : `domain.com/app{anything else}` wont work.

When I try different permalink setting I get different results.

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want is:

```
add_rewrite_rule('/app.*', 'index.php?page_id=11', 'top');
```

But you need to tighten up the url structure as much as possible, for example the above will match `/appetizer` `/applease`  etc. since they are all leading to the same page your first attempt was probably correct, `/app/` and then add whatever you want after the `/`

Comment: work for what url? btw did you go to permalinks and click on the save button before trying? you need to do this after adding rewrite rules